# Create 3D Room based on Line Drawing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm provide LineRenderer to draw the shape of Room in 2D and store the LineRenderer position values in DrawLine.storeLineRenderers list.(List2>)

My plan to create 3D room using 2D Shape , i.e LineRenderer's.

[image]

Following code gives convert to 3d, but not accurate

```
for(int i=1;i<=noOfLines;i++)
    {
        LineRenderer line =GameObject.Find("line" + i).GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if(line!=null)
        {
          Vector3[] ss=  DrawLine.storeLineRenderers[i - 1];
          print(ss[0]);  //Position Element 0 value (Vector3)
          print(ss[1]);  //Position Element 1 value (Vector3)

            //generate 3d box (wall) here
          GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
          cube.name = "wall" + i;
          cube.transform.localPosition =new Vector3(ss[0].x,ss[0].y,ss[0].z);

          cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ss[1].x - ss[0].x, ss[1].y - ss[0].y,ss[1].z - ss[0].z);

        }
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

How to solve this?? Is there any formula to create properly??

thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean 2d to 3d? You can do the other way around but in order to draw 3d with 2d you need a z parameter.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this out.
What you have to be aware of is that the cube's pivot is in its center, meaning you have to add half its size to its position to make it "start" at ss[0] and span all the way to ss[1].

Also, the wall need to be rotated to look at ss[1].

```
const float thickness = .1f; // how thick will the wall be
const float height = 1f; // how high will the wall be


Vector3 dist = ss[1] - ss[0];
float length = dist.magnitude; // make wall long enough to span ss[0] to ss[1]

Vector3 cubeSize = new Vector3(thickness, height, length);
Vector3 cubePos = ss[0] + (cubeSize * 0.5f); // cube pivot is in its center
Quaternion cubeOrientation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dist, Vector3.up); // rotate to look at ss[1]

GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
cube.transform.localPosition = cubePos;
cube.transform.localScale = cubeSize;
cube.transform.localRotation = cubeOrientation;
```